# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'quantize' using django-firebird

Tags: django

I'm using:
Django 2.2.24,
django-firebird 2.2a1,
fdb 2.02,

my model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  ...
  total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True)
  ...
```

When i run a simple query:

```
ml = MyModel.objects.values('id', 'total').last()
```

I got this error:
*AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'quantize'*

I guess the issue is with converters from firebird/operations.py

Full traceback:

```
~/.pyenv/versions/crm-nov21/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in last(self)
    656     def last(self):
    657         """Return the last object of a query or None if no match is found."""
--> 658         for obj in (self.reverse() if self.ordered else self.order_by('-pk'))[:1]:
    659             return obj
    660

~/.pyenv/versions/crm-nov21/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in __iter__(self)
    272                - Responsible for turning the rows into model objects.
    273         """
--> 274         self._fetch_all()
    275         return iter(self._result_cache)
    276

~/.pyenv/versions/crm-nov21/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in _fetch_all(self)
   1240     def _fetch_all(self):
   1241         if self._result_cache is None:
-> 1242             self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
   1243         if self._prefetch_related_lookups and not self._prefetch_done:
   1244             self._prefetch_related_objects()

~/.pyenv/versions/crm-nov21/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in __iter__(self)
    111         ]
    112         indexes = range(len(names))
--> 113         for row in compiler.results_iter(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size):
    114             yield {names[i]: row[i] for i in indexes}
    115

~/.pyenv/versions/crm-nov21/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py in apply_converters(self, rows, converters)
   1084                 value = row[pos]
   1085                 for converter in convs:
-> 1086                     value = converter(value, expression, connection)
   1087                 row[pos] = value
   1088             yield row

~/.pyenv/versions/crm-nov21/lib/python3.7/site-packages/firebird/operations.py in convert_decimalfield_value(self, value, expression, connection, context)
    304         field = expression.field
    305
--> 306         val = utils.format_number(value, field.max_digits, field.decimal_places)
    307         value = decimal.Decimal.from_float(float(val))
    308         return value

~/.pyenv/versions/crm-nov21/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in format_number(value, max_digits, decimal_places)
    236         context.prec = max_digits
    237     if decimal_places is not None:
--> 238         value = value.quantize(decimal.Decimal(1).scaleb(-decimal_places), context=context)
    239     else:
    240         context.traps[decimal.Rounded] = 1

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'quantize'
```

could someone help me please ?

Comment: Can you share the view, ... where you use this queryset and share the *full* traceback?

Comment: quantize() is a method on the Decimal class. Sounds like somewhere there's a floating point value where a decimal is expected. https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/decimal.html#quick-start-tutorial It's hard to say without seeing the traceback.

Comment: It looks like you have set a `float` in the `.total` field, but it expects a `Decimal`.

Comment: my view is some extense, so I'm testing with django shell to avoid a lot of unnecessary context

Comment: @MiguelPonzzi: are you sure the database uses a `DECIMAL` field, and not a `FLOAT` field?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: yes, I'm sure, I'm using DecimalField, actually I have 9 DecimalField on this model

Comment: @MiguelPonzzi: yes, but if you used a `FloatField` previously, it is possible that you did not migrate the database properly, and it thus still contains that column as a `FLOAT` column.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you're right, these fields were created as DOUBLE PRECISION, for my first version I used DecimalField in my django models to represent this Double Precision fields, but now that I'm upgrading django-firebird from 1.8 to 2.2a1 aren't compatibles with DecimalField, but using FloatField works fine